# Consul lookups stop working after loss of a single node in cluster

Tags: consul

Hoping to get some help on how consul is suppose to behave in the following scenario.

I have two consul clusters of 3 servers each setup in separate AZs but have used join -wan to connect them. All agents are v0.8.5. Using 'members -wan' I can see all the servers are gossiping.

I just ran a test where I had a server in one AZ1 executing DNS lookups using the name.service.datacenter.consul format in a loop against itself for a server in AZ2. This worked great, until I shutdown a single server in AZ2. After a few minutes, AZ1 can no longer do lookups of services in AZ2. Bring the server back up and lookups start working again or wait several more minutes with the server down and lookups will start working again. Local lookups continue working in AZ2, just not WAN lookups. Is this expected behavior? Any documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to share some of the configuration of your cluster, it's difficult to judge without it.

However, from the look of it right now, it looks like a datacenter misconfiguration because since Consul 0.8.0 added WAN join flooding, so if one Consul server in a datacenter joins the WAN, it will automatically join the other servers in its local datacenter that it knows about via the LAN. So technically as long as you have the agent running on the machine it should be able to get the information via gossip from other nodes in the DC.